# How do you remove collapsed whitespace between HTML elements?

Tags: html, css, whitespace, removing-whitespace

I have a `UL` with `LI`s that will be displayed horizontally using `display:inline-block`. However, these collapse all whitespace (including newlines and tabs) to a single space between the elements, when I require they be perfectly flush for measurement purposes; I don't want my measurements thrown off by varying sizes of spaces among fonts.

**Is there any way to remove whitespace from between these?**
I need this done without having control of the HTML; this will be for a small proof-of-concept framework that shows it can be made without abusing `float`

SSCCE: http://jsfiddle.net/nSsTP/

```
<ul>
    <li>Semantic Cell 1</li>
    <li>Semantic Cell 2</li>
    <li>Semantic Cell 3</li>
    <li>Pretty Cell 4</li><li>Pretty Cell 5</li><li>Pretty Cell 6</li>
</ul>
<style>
    ul>li{
        background: gray;
        display: inline-block;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: I need a solution in CSS, as I have no control over the HTML in this project

Comment: Here is a CSS solution.. http://jsfiddle.net/JoshC/nSsTP/2/

Comment: @JoshC I like that, except that it then ignores its parent's set font size. Any ideas on how that could be respected?

Comment: I am afraid that is your only solution if you can't modify the HTML. Alternatively, if you use JS you could remove the whitespace from the DOM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`inline-block` leaves white-space between elements.

To remove this space, write elements on same line.

Change

```
<ul>
    <li>Semantic Cell 1</li>
    <li>Semantic Cell 2</li>
    <li>Semantic Cell 3</li>
    <li>Pretty Cell 4</li><li>Pretty Cell 5</li><li>Pretty Cell 6</li>
</ul>
```

to

```
<ul>
    <li>Semantic Cell 1</li><li>Semantic Cell 2</li><li>Semantic Cell 3</li><li>Pretty Cell 4</li><li>Pretty Cell 5</li><li>Pretty Cell 6</li>
</ul>
```

[**Demo here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/nSsTP/1/)

OR:

Pure css solution:

```
ul{font-size:0;}
li{font-size:1rem;}
```

[**Demo here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/nSsTP/8/)

Comment: I need a solution in CSS, as I have no control over the HTML in this project

Comment: Do you have a way to then make the font size in the `LI`s the same as the `UL`'s parent?

Comment: I've changed `li` font size to `1rem`, or 1 root em, to hopefully help match the parent

Answer (score 2):

You can use one more style tag for

```
ul    
    {      
    font-size: 0;
}
```

OR

```
ul>li
    {
         display: inline-block;    
        background: gray;
        float:left;
}
```

Hope this will really help.

Comment: I like that font size solution... Do you have a way to then make the font size in the `LI`s the same as the UL's parent?

Comment: Hi...Supuhstar, You can use **width: 100%; and height: 100%;**  in li style.

Comment: Sorry Supuhstar , but u can use **Height:100%** in Ul tag as well as in li to make LIs size the same as the UL's parent. Width:100% is changing structure...

Comment: That's not what this question is about... All I care is that the whitespace between the items is gone

Answer (score 1):

I was trying your code.
Your white spaces can be removed if you put your all list items

one by one without hitting an enter....

```
<ul>
    <li>Semantic Cell 1</li><li>Semantic Cell 2</li><li>Semantic Cell 3</li><li>Pretty Cell 4</li><li>Pretty Cell 5</li><li>Pretty Cell 6</li>
</ul>
```

Let me knw if its not working..

Comment: I need a solution in CSS, as I have no control over the HTML in this project

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `inline-block`, you can display them as `block` elements and use `float: left`:

```
ul>li{
    background: gray;
    display: block;
    float: left;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4r3rB/)

Comment: I'd rather never use `float` unless doing Wikipedia-style thumbnail figures

Comment: If you can't control the HTML, sometimes you have to do things you don't like.